Kiali - No traffic showing from "Passthrough cluster"
I'm running an AKS (Kubernates on Azure) cluster, with their own Istio plugin (Puts istio into aks-istio).
As a result, I've had to jump through some config hoops to redirect everything to the right namespace for Istio - everything works.
Apart from Kiali - I'm not seeing any outbound traffic beyond Pass Through Cluster.

I do have REGISTRY_ONLY set, and it works, as soon as I remove my Service Entries traffic stops - but I'd like to be able to see traffic out.
I presume it's because I don't have Prometheus setup correctly - as I can't find any references to PassThrough Cluster in my data - but also, no docs to help set it up.
I have two Service Monitiors setup - which bring through the bulk of my traffic - just missing the cluster.
    {
    "apiVersion": "monitoring.coreos.com/v1",
    "kind": "ServiceMonitor",
    "metadata": {
        "labels": {
            "monitoring": "istio-dataplane",
            "release": "prometheus"
        },
        "name": "prometheus-oper-istio-dataplane",
        "namespace": "monitoring",

    "spec": {
        "endpoints": [
            {
                "interval": "15s",
                "path": "/stats/prometheus",
                "relabelings": [
                    {
                        "action": "keep",
                        "regex": "istio-proxy",
                        "sourceLabels": [
                            "__meta_kubernetes_pod_container_name"
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "action": "keep",
                        "sourceLabels": [
                            "__meta_kubernetes_pod_annotationpresent_prometheus_io_scrape"
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "action": "replace",
                        "regex": "([^:]+)(?::\\d+)?;(\\d+)",
                        "replacement": "$1:$2",
                        "sourceLabels": [
                            "__address__",
                            "__meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_port"
                        ],
                        "targetLabel": "__address__"
                    },
                    {
                        "action": "keep",
                        "regex": ".*-envoy-prom",
                        "sourceLabels": [
                            "__meta_kubernetes_pod_container_port_name"
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "action": "labelmap",
                        "regex": "__meta_kubernetes_pod_label_(.+)"
                    },
                    {
                        "action": "replace",
                        "sourceLabels": [
                            "__meta_kubernetes_namespace"
                        ],
                        "targetLabel": "namespace"
                    },
                    {
                        "action": "replace",
                        "sourceLabels": [
                            "__meta_kubernetes_pod_name"
                        ],
                        "targetLabel": "pod_name"
                    }
                ],
                "targetPort": "http-envoy-prom"
            }
        ],
        "jobLabel": "envoy-stats",
        "namespaceSelector": {
            "any": true
        },
        "selector": {
            "matchExpressions": [
                {
                    "key": "istio-prometheus-ignore",
                    "operator": "DoesNotExist"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}

{
    "apiVersion": "monitoring.coreos.com/v1",
    "kind": "ServiceMonitor",
    "metadata": {
        "labels": {
            "release": "prometheus"
        },
        
        "name": "prometheus-oper-istio-controlplane",
        "namespace": "monitoring",
        "resourceVersion": "1152559",
        "uid": "6c4a1080-e2ff-456c-ae86-23caaf73fe73"
    },
    "spec": {
        "endpoints": [
            {
                "interval": "15s",
                "port": "http-monitoring"
            },
            {
                "interval": "15s",
                "port": "http-policy-monitoring"
            }
        ],
        "jobLabel": "istio",
        "namespaceSelector": {
            "any": true
        },
        "selector": {
            "matchExpressions": [
                {
                    "key": "istio",
                    "operator": "In",
                    "values": [
                        "mixer",
                        "pilot",
                        "galley",
                        "citadel",
                        "sidecar-injector"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}


